# Emacs visual-line-hook?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to turn on adaptive-wrap (adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode) when I turn on visual-line-mode, but it seems there's no visual-line-hook. Any suggestions for other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I think I found it. It's called `visual-line-mode-hook`. So, solution is this:

```
(add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook 'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
```

Comment: The vast majority of modes automatically have an associated hook named using that same pattern (`foo-mode-hook` for `foo-mode`), as the standard mode-definition macros take care of that automatically. (The exceptions being the occasional mode which does not use the macros or manually run such a hook.)